# mvc - ActionNameAttribute get from resources?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, resources, attributes

Hi i have been looking for some solutions but i have found nothing...

Is there a way to use resources with the ActionNameAttribute?

For example with DisplayNameAttribute in properties we can resort to:

```
    [Display(Name = "labelForName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))] 
    public string name{ get; set; }
```

But I do not know a way to use resources for my action methods...

Thanks¡

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a custom attribute to achieve this task:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=false, Inherited=true)]
public sealed class LocalizedActionNameAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public LocalizedActionNameAttribute(string name, Type resourceType)
    {
        Name = name;
        ResourceType = resourceType;
    }

    public Type ResourceType { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var rm = new ResourceManager(ResourceType);
        var name = rm.GetString(Name);
        return string.Equals(actionName, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[LocalizedActionName("Index", typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```